# Outputting a lists contents in a label in unity

Tags: c#, string, list, unity-game-engine

This is silly question I feel daft for asking but I can't get it to work on my own.

I've got a list full of debug data I want to render to my screen in a label but when I try the following call in my OnGUI function (outputContent is the name of label I was the data passed to):

```
debugList.ForEach(item => outputContent.text);
```

I get the following error:

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

How can I get the data from my list to be displayed in a label?

Comment: You seem to misunderstand the lambda syntax. `x => y` really means `delegate(var x) { y; }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this possibly?

```
debugList.ForEach(item => outputContent.text += item);
```